# I've run some commands without actually knowing what they do on windows

Tags: windows-10, command-line, gaming

A long while ago, I wanted to play a game called Insurgency. Unfortunately, after buying it, I realized it wouldn't start, so I checked their [FAQ page](http://support.newworldinteractive.com/kb/article/5-wmi-startup-crash). The solution that I found to be working for me was this:

> WMI Startup Crash
>
> If you are crashing at start-up in shaderapidx9.dll, then you may have a Windows installation with broken WMI.
>
> The quick way of fixing this is to gain ownership of C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wbem\FASTPROX.DLL and renaming it to something else (eg. FASTPROX.BAK). >Alternatively, this can be fixed by opening an admin command prompt window and typing the following commands:

```
net stop winmgmt
winmgmt /standalonehost
winmgmt /resetrepository
```

After running the commands present there, the issue was solved and I could play. However, I noticed a weird thing.

Each time I was starting Windows (after about 2-3 minutes actually) I got a message saying that the Windows security service couldn't be started:

[image: initial error]

After trying to manually start it, I got this error:

[image: second error]

Finally, I thought that starting it from the Services app would solve it. It didn't:

[image: third error]

I then tried seeing what dependencies that service needed, however, when clicking the dependencies tab, I got this:

[image: final message]

Closing it would just show an empty dependency list.
I'm sure the cause of this is the commands I ran. Everything was fine until I restarted the computer in order to finish the steps the Insurgency guys presented in their FAQ, so I guess there should be some way to undo that?
Again, sorry if this post might be irrelevant to this community (it probably is), but I've really got no better place to ask.
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Seth for editing. I couldn't include more than 2 links due to my reputation, so I tried only using 2 while still providing the images. Didn't realize I could just include the images directly.

Comment: Have you tried restoring he FASTPROX.DLL from backup? The guide you have followed suggested you to rename it and keep the old copy - you should still have it and be able to restore the original file. Try it and see if this has any impact on your problem

Comment: I have restored it and restarted my computer, but it still happens ;(

Comment: Please execute the following command: `winmgmt /verifyrepository` in an elevated command prompt and post the resulting output here. If the previous command does not report that repository is consistent, then try `winmgmt /salvagerepository`

Comment: Don't worry. I'm not even sure you would be able to include them yourself. You usually need some reputation for that. But if you include links to images it's pretty common that someone will transfer them.

Comment: Thank you both ArtGertner and Seth for your help. I've however managed to solve the issue by reinstalling windows, so I think running the commands ArtGertner suggested would be pretty pointless now. Thanks anyways!